# Automatically refresh browser for ASP.NET Core based Angular 2 app changes

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I recently started using Angular 2 with ASP.NET Core. I use Webpack to get rid of the auto-loading mess from SystemJs, which caused my app to load horrible 400 js-files for hello world in Angular. I found [WebPackTaskRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner) for integrating Webpack in Visual Studio. Using [this](http://www.sochix.ru/how-to-integrate-webpack-into-visual-studio-2015/) article, I configured VS so that the Webpack watcher is started on project load.

This toolkit let me change my Angular 2 app using CTRL + S, a few seconds later the scripts are compiled and I can refresh it in the browser. I would like to automate this, so that the browser refresh itself, when some js files had changed. Found out this can be done using [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html). The problem with them is: It starts another webserver (e.g. on port 8080) and all my routes are broken.

For example I want to fetch data from **Users/GetAll**, normally this is on the debugging server (http://localhost:5000/api/Users/GetAll). Since the app runs on localhost:8080 using webpack devserver, the app tries to request http://localhost:8080/api/Users/GetAll which surely can't work since its no ASP.NET Core webserver. To work around this, I had to specify a base url. And I need to start both webservers (ASP.NET Core and Webpack dev)

Whats best practice for doing live refreshs in Angular 2 using ASP.NET Core with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

WebPack bundles your Angular 2 app and make ease while you are developing, because It watch for file changes on the directory of the project. It runs in a new light-weight http server to show up your app at the browser.

You should turn on CORS for your ASP.NET Core and It will work with the Angular 2 app running in a different domain, as you are having issues with the localhost:8080 to localhost:5000.

[Enabling Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors)

Also, you should put the URL for the service somewhere you can change one time for everyone, not hardcoded inside any place you need to perform a http call. This file should contain the URL for every environment you have, like: Development, Staging and Production. You can configure WebPack to choose the URL based on the build parameter.

[AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-pass-environment-variables%3F)